# Thalie, split verses, adjusting vertical alignment

Tags: alignment

I am looking for a way to vertically align split verses in a dramatic text with the `\pauseverse`, `\resumeverse` commands from the `thalie` package. As the documentation of thalie already says, the feature often does not work correctly, hence the `\adjustverse` command to manipulate the space that is needed for vertical alignment. When typesetting a whole play it is very tedious though to go through all instances and find a manual adjustment.

The following is a MWE for my case:

```
\documentclass [12pt, a4paper, pagesize] {scrbook}
\usepackage [UKenglish] {babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}


\usepackage[characterstyle=imprimerie-prose]{thalie}

\usepackage{hanging}
\renewcommand*{\speakswithoutdirection}[1]{%
    \hangpara{2\parindent}{1}\noindent\textsc{#1}\xspace.%
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{dramatis}[hidden]
    \character[cmd={Buckingham}]{Buckingham}
    \character[cmd={Norfolk}]{Norfolk}
\end{dramatis}

\Buckingham
Good morrow and well met. How have ye done\\Since last we saw in France?\pauseverse

\Norfolk
\resumeverse I thank your grace,\\Healthful, and ever since a fresh admirer\\Of what I saw there.\pauseverse

\Buckingham\resumeverse An untimely ague\\Stayed me a prisoner in my chamber when\\Those suns of glory, those two lights of men,\\Met in the vale of Andres.\pauseverse

\end{document}
```

The alignment is way off in both cases. I guess the correct spacing depends on the length of the first half line and on the length of the character's name that starts the second half line. I tried to read both lengths with `\predisplaysize` within modified `\pauseverse` and `\resumeverse` commands to try calculating the correct length of empty space needed; but I got nowhere.

So my question is: Is there a way of

**a)** calculating the correct adjustment length for `\adjustverse` for each instance of split verses; or

**b)** calculating the correct `\hspace` that `\resumeverse` must use, without adjusting with `\adjustverse`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spacing doesn't take into account the character's name and the standard 2em inserted by TeX.

```latex
\documentclass [12pt, a4paper, pagesize] {scrbook}
\usepackage [UKenglish] {babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[characterstyle=imprimerie-prose]{thalie}
\usepackage{hanging}


\newlength{\brokenverse}
\renewcommand*{\speakswithoutdirection}[1]{%
  \settowidth{\brokenverse}{\textsc{#1}.}%
  \hangpara{2\parindent}{1}\noindent\textsc{#1}.%
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\resumeverse}{%
  \hspace{\@verseadjust}\hspace{\dimexpr\dimen\@ne-\brokenverse-2em}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{dramatis}[hidden]
    \character[cmd={Buckingham}]{Buckingham}
    \character[cmd={Norfolk}]{Norfolk}
\end{dramatis}

\Buckingham
Good morrow and well met. How have ye done\\
Since last we saw in France?\pauseverse

\Norfolk
\resumeverse I thank your grace,\\
Healthful, and ever since a fresh admirer\\
Of what I saw there.\pauseverse

\Buckingham
\resumeverse An untimely ague\\
Stayed me a prisoner in my chamber when\\
Those suns of glory, those two lights of men,\\
Met in the vale of Andres.\pauseverse

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That solution is perfect. Many thanks.