# reledpar (& thalie): option advancedshiftedpstarts upsets paragraph beginnings and line numbering

Tags: reledpar

I'm trying to use the `advancedshiftedpstarts` option of `reledpar` for typesetting a parallel bilingual edition of a dramatic text with the `thalie` package; the left page is a prose version, the right are verse lines. I'd like to avoid white spaces between paragraphs with the `advancedshiftedpstarts` option; unfortunately it mangles the output of text lines and also upsets the counting of lines on the right page (the last line displayed on the right page should be line 5):

```
\documentclass [12pt, a4paper, pagesize] {scrbook}
\usepackage [UKenglish, german] {babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{libertine}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[characterstyle=imprimerie-prose]{thalie}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage[advancedshiftedpstarts]{reledpar}
%%\usepackage{reledpar}


\usepackage{hanging}

%% adjusting hanging for each spoken bit and adjusting correct length of second part of a broken verse
%% see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/545307/thalie-split-verses-adjusting-vertical-alignment
\newlength{\brokenverse}
\renewcommand*{\speakswithoutdirection}[1]{%
  \settowidth{\brokenverse}{\textsc{#1}.}%
  \hangpara{2\parindent}{1}\noindent\textsc{#1}.%
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\resumeverse}{%
  \hspace{\@verseadjust}\hspace{\dimexpr\dimen\@ne-\brokenverse-2em}
}
\makeatother


\linenummargin{right}

%%line numbers for broken half lines on last bit of line
\lockdisp{last}

%%line numbers on right pages without R flag
\setRlineflag{}

%%suppress line numbers on left pages
\firstlinenum{10000000}

\begin{document}

\begin{dramatis}[hidden]
    \character[cmd={Buckingham}]{Buckingham}
    \character[cmd={Norfolk}]{Norfolk}
\end{dramatis}



\begin{pages}
    \begin{Leftside}
        \beginnumbering
        \pstart\Buckingham  \blindtext\pend

\pstart\Norfolk  \blindtext\pend

\pstart\Buckingham  \blindtext\pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}


    \begin{Rightside}
        \beginnumbering
        \selectlanguage{UKenglish}
        \pstart\Buckingham Good morrow and well met. How have ye done\\Since last we saw in France?\pauseverse\startlock\pend

\pstart\Norfolk\resumeverse\endlock I thank your grace,\\Healthful, and ever since a fresh admirer\\Of what I saw there.\pauseverse\startlock\pend

\pstart\Buckingham\resumeverse\endlock An untimely ague\\Stayed me a prisoner in my chamber when\pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages


\end{document}
```

[image: example of mangled output]

Without the `advancedshiftedpstarts` option all lines look ok, and the displayed line numbering is correct:
[image: example without option]
What am I missing about `advancedshiftedpstarts`?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, I thinkg that some of the macro of thalie insert vertcial spacing... and reledmac/par does not work well with vertical space inside pstart...pend structure. So I have no solution (and I won't take time to make thalie and reledpar compatible), except telling you to try to use all the builtin feature of reledmac/reledpar, which include also hanging verse and similar feature.

Comment: I confirm that the problem is with \pauseverse and \resumeverse of the thalie package, which introduce vertical spacing.... which reledmac/reledpar does not like. You should use native reledmac verse features.

Comment: Thank you @Maïeul for looking into this and confirming that the vertical spacing introduced by \pauseverse creates the problem. The thalie functions for handling characters and split verses are quite essential to me and I'm not sure how I'd go about recreating these with native reledmac/reledpar features.

Comment: For the moment I have isolated the relevant bit from the \pauseverse command and i've tried to move it outside the pstart...pend structure: \AtEveryPend{\vskip\dimexpr-\parskip-\baselineskip\relax}; this works for the verse lines on the right page, but it also affects the left page, where it is never needed, and it still upsets the line counting. I've tried to make the \AtEveryPend addition conditional with \ifledRcol but had no success so far... and even that would still leave me with upset line numbers on the right page.

Comment: You should look at \stanza feature of reledmac / reledpar for verse....

Comment: I am aware of the \stanza / \astanza environment and I am afraid that some specific demands for setting dramatic texts in verse are not met by it. If every speech by a character is treated as a separate \stanza / \astanza, how is the line numbering across all "stanzas" in a scene ensured and displayed? How could the alignment of "split verses" be reconciled with a general "hanging" indention pattern of \setstanzaindents{0,1}, \setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}?

Comment: I am following up your suggestion to set dramatic verse with the \stanza feature and have opened a new question: [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/546309/reledmac-using-stanza-environment-for-dramatic-verse)