# reledmac: using stanza environment for dramatic verse

Tags: alignment, reledmac, verse

This question is a follow-up to [reledpar (& thalie): option advancedshiftedpstarts upsets paragraph beginnings and line numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/546105/reledpar-thalie-option-advancedshiftedpstarts-upsets-paragraph-beginnings-a)

I am trying to make the `\stanza` environment of `eledmac` (and consequently the `astanza` environment of `eledpar`)suitable for the setting of dramatic verse. At present I am retaining functions from the `thalie` package for the management of characters in the play. The following MWE shows an example of dramatic lines with the following things missing:

1. there is no line numeration displayed at all. The last line of verse is supposed to be line 5 in the play. Am I forgetting an "easy" setting?
2. while the general hanging indention works fine for all lines in a stanza following the first, the first lines in a speech should leave space between the character's name and his first words in order to reflect the metrical nature of a "split verse." Since this always occurs in a `\startlock` `\endlock` configuration, my guess is that these two commands would be the point to determine the length of the needed empty space and also set it. I am at a loss, however, how to implement that.

MWE:

```
\documentclass [12pt, a4paper, pagesize] {scrbook}
\usepackage [UKenglish] {babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage[characterstyle=imprimerie-prose]{thalie}

\usepackage{reledmac}


%%retained from the thalie package, modifies the way a character's name is given in the first line of speech
\renewcommand*{\speakswithoutdirection}[1]{%
   \noindent\textsc{#1}\xspace.%
    }



%%line numbers for broken half lines on last bit of line
\lockdisp{last}

\begin{document}

\begin{dramatis}[hidden]
    \character[cmd={Buckingham}]{Buckingham}
    \character[cmd={Norfolk}]{Norfolk}
\end{dramatis}

%sets indent for stanza at 2\parindent for all lines following the first in a stanza
\setlength\stanzaindentbase{2\parindent}
\setstanzaindents{0,1}
\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}

    \beginnumbering
        \selectlanguage{UKenglish}
        \stanza\Buckingham Good morrow and well met. How have ye done&Since last we saw in France?\startlock\&

        \stanza\Norfolk\endlock I thank your grace,&Healthful, and ever since a fresh admirer&Of what I saw there.\startlock\&

\stanza\Buckingham\endlock An untimely ague&Stayed me a prisoner in my chamber when\&
        \endnumbering


\end{document}
```

[image: eledmac verse]

This is how the alignment of "split verses" is supposed to look (in a different font though).

[image: aligned split verses]

Many thanks for your help.

Additional example for lineation:

Even with `\firstlinenum{1}`, `\linenumincrement{1}` and `\linenummargin{right}` I could not get any display of line numbers >1 in my MWE, so I added them myself to show how it is supposed to look if each line number were displayed (please excuse my poor drawing skills)

[image: verse line numbering]

Apologies for the piecemal editing. I've created another example that shows how both issues (horizontal spacing in split verse, and lineation) are supposed to look. This one was created by `thalie`'s functions in `\pstart` `\pend` environments (unusable in a `ledpar` parallel setting with the `advancedshiftedpstarts` option due to vertical skips, as brought up in the related question named at the top).

[image: ideal look of both issues]

Comment: For your indent problem, please open an issue on github reledmac, with this MWE. I think I could try to add this as a feature of reledmac.

I am not sur to understand well your problem with lineation, could you please add an example of the desired output.

Comment: Many thanks for your attention to this. I have added an example concerning the lineation. I have no experience using github but I will try to open an issue.

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand the logic of your lineation. In which case you does not want the line number ?  I don't understand the logic in your example.

Comment: Some lines are "complete", they contain the necessary number of stresses to make up a line of e.g. pentameter or hexameter. They should always count as a line and advance the line counter. Then there are lines that are "incomplete", they do not contain the necessary number of stresses; such a line is "split" and "continued" by the next speaker; both parts together carry the necessary number of stresses. In these cases, the 1st "half line" should not advance the line counter (`\setlock`), the 2nd then `\endlock`s and advances linecounter, this needs manual setting for all cases (fine with me).

Comment: in this case, I think it will better for you to use `\skipnumbering` instead of `\startlock` ... `\endlock`

Comment: Thanks, indeed, `\skipnumbering` takes care of the lineation in the way I want it to appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question asked for some features which didn't exist on reledmac. After having asked on github, I implemented these features on reledmac 2.33.1 / reledpar 2.24.0.

This version will be release ASAP on CTAN.

For other users of SE, here the answer to the question.

### 1. Split a line of verse in two

The antilabe mechanism (a line of verse splitted in two because the speaker change) is implemented in the new version of reledmac.

You just have to

1. Load the package with the `antilabe` option.
2. Add `\antilabe` at the beginning of the secund half of the line of verse.
3. Optionally, you can redefine `\afterantilabe` if you want to add more space, for example `\renewcommand{\afterantilabe}{\hspace{1em}`.

### 2. Don't count the first half of the line in the total line number

Use `\skipnumbering` instead of `\start`...`\endlock`

### 3. Set indents

Not a part of your initial question, but if you want to have the first line of a stanza not indented and all other lines indented by 1, you may use the following settings:

```
\setstanzaindents{1,0,1}
\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}
\setcounter{startstanzaindentsrepetition}{2}
```

`startstanzaindentsrepetition` is a new feature of reledmac 2.33.0

### 4 Some remarks

All your setting about indent, and in general all reledmac/reledpar settings should be in the preamble, for code clarity.

### 5 final code

Here the final code, which is now a part of reledmac documentation, thanks you :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[osf,p]{libertinus}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babeltags{english = english}

\usepackage[characterstyle=imprimerie-prose]{thalie}

\usepackage[noeledsec,noend,noledgroup,nofamiliar,nocritical,antilabe]{reledmac}
\setstanzaindents{1,0,1}
\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}
\setcounter{startstanzaindentsrepetition}{2}

\linenumincrement{1}
\firstlinenum{1}
%%retained from the thalie package, modifies the way a character's name is given in the first line of speech
\renewcommand*{\speakswithoutdirection}[1]{%
  \noindent\textsc{#1}\xspace.%
}

% Space after \antilabe macro
\renewcommand{\afterantilabe}{\hspace{1em}}
\begin{document}


\begin{abstract}
This file provides an example of typesetting verse for a dramatic text with reledmac and thalie packages.

We use the thalie features to manage characters.

We use the following features of reledmac to typeset the verses:
\begin{itemize}
  \item \verb+\antilabe+ to show correctly the second half of a split line of verse (antilabe);
  \item \verb+\afterantilabe+ to add more space after \verb+\antilabe+;
  \item \verb+\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}+ and \\  \verb+\setcounter{startstanzaindentsrepetition}+ to have the first line of a reply/stanza indented, but not the following ones;
  \item \verb+\skipnumbering+ to avoid counting the first half of an antilabe in the line counting.
\end{itemize}
\end{abstract}

ddd
%%part of thalie's management of characters
\begin{dramatis}
  \character[cmd={Buckingham}]{Buckingham}
  \character[cmd={Norfolk}]{Norfolk}
\end{dramatis}

% Normal typesetting
\beginnumbering
\stanza\Buckingham Good morrow and well met. How have ye done&
\skipnumbering Since last we saw in France?\&
\stanza\antilabe\Norfolk I thank your grace,&
Healthful, and ever since a fresh admirer&
\skipnumbering Of what I saw there.\&
\stanza\antilabe\Buckingham An untimely ague&
Stayed me a prisoner in my chamber when\&
\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for implementing these new features. I edited the explanation of the example in 3. about the indenting pattern and fixed one typo.

Comment: yes, thank you...

Comment: About `\antilabe`: Unfortunately I forgot to test for instances where the character's name consists of more than one word. E.g. defining `\character[cmd={FSecretary}]{First Secretary}` with the `thalie` package, "First Secretary" is broken apart on the line when called with `\stanza\antilabe\FSecretary`. The same happens without using `thalie`'s features and using \stanza\antilabe{First Secretary}. `\stanza\antilabe{\mbox{First Secretary}}`seems a workaround for the latter case, but it doesn't work with the command defined by `thalie'.

Comment: Upon further testing `\antilabe` with character names of two or more words and the `thalie` package: using an `\mbox` within the `thalie`character definition seems to work: `\character[cmd={FSecretary}]{\mbox{First Secretary}}` will keep "First Secretary" together at the beginning of the line when called with `\stanza\antilabe\FSecretary`.

Comment: I think it would have beend bette to do `\antilabe{\FSecretary} without using any \mbox as box is for typographical setting...

Comment: Putting the command in braces does not work. There is still a long white space between the first and second word of the character's name.

Comment: Sorry, I did'unt understand well the problem. In this case, do `\antilabe{\FSecretary\hfill}`. Maybe I should implement that directly, as I don't see any case where the long with space is required.

Comment: what do you think ?

Comment: Ah, I did not know that `\hfill` is the proper solution. You are right, I cannot think of a use case where the long white space would be desirable.

Comment: well, it was a bug, so the proper solution would have been to open an issue :). The release v2.33.1, which will be send on the CTAN soon, fix it.

Comment: Thank you for taking care of that.